# Show continue date -SQL

Tags: sql

How I can get all people who has code (14 ,13)for whole month

```
IDNR       CODE        START-DATE          END -DATE       
 16         13         2021-01-07          2021-01-21 
 16         13         2021-01-22          2021-01-31
 17         13         2021-01-01          2021-01-01
 17         12         2021-01-02          2021-01-14
 17         14         2021-01-15          2021-01-31
 18         14         2021-01-01          2021-01-19
 18         13         2021-01-20          2021-01-29
 18         14         2021-01-30          2021-01-31
```

Result that i want  is :

```
IDNR       CODE        START-DATE          END -DATE       
 16         13         2021-01-07          2021-01-21 
 16         13         2021-01-22          2021-01-31
 18         14         2021-01-01          2021-01-19
 18         13         2021-01-20          2021-01-29
 18         14         2021-01-30          2021-01-31
```

I chose ( idnr=16 , idnr=18 )as result, because  CODE 13,  CODE 14  that i want AND start-date and end -date  cover all january(whole month 2021-01-01 to 2021-01-31)
**Sorry to repeat my question but i delete it yesterday because it wasnot so good **

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.end_date >= '2021-01-01' and
      t.start_date < '2021-02-01'
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.idnr = t.idnr and
                        t2.code not in (13, 14) and
                        t2.end_date >= '2021-01-01' and
                        t2.start_date < '2021-02-01'
                 )
```

Comment: thanks for help but this query give me  person that i donnot want ! @Gordon Linoff